# Adding 3D background like Sketchfab.com

Tags: html5-canvas, x3d, x3dom

In Shetchfab.com you can add a [3d background environment](https://sketchfab.com/models/1db7c620d7f74398b43d0e64dfcf0d96) for your 3d objects.

Im making this page where i show an .x3d object in a tag frame using [x3dom](http://www.x3dom.org/).

```
<x3d height='500px'>
    <scene id="mainScene">
         <Inline id="inlineBox" nameSpaceName="dcm" url="juicecarton.x3d" />
    </scene>                                        
</x3d>
```

How do i add a background like Sketchfab with the rotating environment ?
Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: WOW seriously no one knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rotating background is often called a "cubemap" (although that name can be used for both, the kind of texture and the way it is being used / visualized in 3D).

In X3DOM, you should be able to use a background like this (inside the Scene element):

```
<Background id='back1' 
        backUrl='"./ocean_3_back.jpg"' bottomUrl='"./ocean_3_bottom.jpg"'
        frontUrl='"./ocean_3_front.jpg"' leftUrl='"./ocean_3_left.jpg"'
        rightUrl='"./ocean_3_right.jpg"' topUrl='"./ocean_3_top.jpg"'>
</Background>
```

There's also an X3DOM node for integrating such texture maps to obtain a reflecting material, it's called "ComposedCubeMapTexture":
https://doc.x3dom.org/author/CubeMapTexturing/ComposedCubeMapTexture.html

I didn't find a live online example, but it should be straightforward to get one working - here's some code:
https://github.com/x3dom/x3dom/blob/master/test/regression-suite/test/cases/cubemap/cubemap.html

Result should look like this:
http://testing.x3dom.org/test/reference/cubemap_0.png

Comment: Thank you brah! You made my day.